# How to use a QT QMap or other dictionary to store function pointers to non static member functions and QT signals of type void

Tags: c++, qt

I need to implement the networking for a computer based implementation of the Cluedo board game for a project for a Software Engineering module, thus integration and consistency across the implementations of all students is very important. The communication protocol that we as a class decided on was to use JSON objects.

My network implementation works by sending a Qt signal for every type of message, that the GUI and GameServer can easily integrate with my code.
When a message is received over the network and it is validated to be a JSON message with a valid "Type" field, I would like to emit a QT signal. I know that too many if statements will be slow and "bad coding" and would thus like to implement it using a dictionary.

Basically

```
QJsonObject message = <messageReceived>;

QMap<QString, void (WebClient::*)(QWebsocket*, QJsonObject jsonMessage)> messageSignals;

// For every signal create a key value pair in the QMap where the key is a valid message type and the value a pointer to the respective signal

messageSignals["type1"] = &signalForMessageType1;

messageSignals["type2"] = &signalForMessageType2;

// Other signals

emit messageSignals[message["Type"].toString];
```

But I keep on getting errors for a reference to void or to non-static member function or that the type of the key field of the QMap is incorrect. All signals and slots have the same arguments `(QWebSocket*, QJsonMessage)` and this is not part of the error. I suspect from my understanding that this is due to the fact that I need to *connect or send the instance of the object to whom the signal belongs* because it is a non-static member function, but I am unsure how to do this.

What is the type of the key field that I should use in the QMap, is this a good solution to my problem and just for the sake of asking would the performance of this solution actually be faster than if statements? I am unsure of the performance cost and complexity of dictionaries in C++ and Qt.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error message(s) verbatim and identify the line(s) of code responsible.

Comment: Your sample seems incomplete, but from what I can see: You can't just call the `WebClient` member functions like that. `emit` is essentially a function call. Basic C++ issue. Before getting any mapping involved, I'd make sure you get the basics of how to call a member function. Right now you're chasing 2 different issues at the same time. Having said that, Qt has a great meta object system (see `QMetaObject` and related). You can invoke signals and slots just by storing meta data about them (not nasty pointers to members), such as the method ID, then invoke them as needed, with arguments.